# Norm of a smooth function is smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry

My lecture notes seem to use this, although I can't shake the feeling that it's wrong. Let $\phi: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ for $n \ge 2$ be smooth (infinitely differentiable) satisfying $|\phi '(t)| \neq 0$ for all $t \in [a,b]$. Then, $|\phi'(t)|$ is also a smooth function.

Does anyone have a nice proof for this? (My first 'counterexample' was $\log$, but it doesn't satisfy the condition $|\phi '(t)| \neq 0$.) Also, is $|\phi(t)|$ a smooth function too?

Although this is from a course in elementary differential geometry, my question is essentially a calculus question...

Comment: Try showing that $\vert\cdot\vert\colon\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ is smooth.

Comment: Since $\phi'$ is nowhere zero, view $||\phi'(t)|||$ as the *composition* of mappings $\phi' \colon [a,b] \to \mathbf R^n - \{\mathbf 0\}$ and $||\cdot|| \colon \mathbf R^n - \{\mathbf 0\} \to \mathbf R$. Show each of those is smooth and you're done. This reduces the issue to showing the norm mapping on $\mathbf R^n$ is smooth away from the origin.

Comment: Minor variant of the above: the norm squared is always smooth. The norm is the composition of the norm squared and the square root function, which is smooth except at zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(v) = \langle v, v\rangle = \lVert v\rVert^2$ and $f(t) = \sqrt{t}$.
Then $\lVert \phi'(t)\rVert = \left(f\circ g\circ\phi'\right)(t)$.

You know that $\phi'$ is smooth and nonvanishing.

It's easy to see that $\nabla_g(v) = 2v$; in other words, $\nabla_g$ is twice the identity, so $g$ is smooth.
It follows that the composition $g\circ \phi'$ is smooth.
Moreover, we have that $g(v) = 0 \iff v = 0$, from which we see that the composition $g\circ\phi'$ is also nonvanishing.

Finally, it's a simple univariate calculus exercise to show that $f:[0,+\infty)\longrightarrow \Bbb R$ is smooth away from the origin.
Hence, the composition $f\circ (g\circ \phi')$ is smooth.