# When is $\|f(x) - y\|$ a smooth function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be a function and $\|\cdot\|_{\mathbb{R}^m}$ be the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Given a point $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$ what conditions does $f$ have to satisfy for the function $h(x) = \|f(x) - y\|_{\mathbb{R}^m}$ to be smooth?

#### Addendum

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993602/norm-of-a-smooth-function-is-smooth) is a related question. My guess is that as long as $f$ is smooth itself, then $h$ is also smooth, but I couldn't prove it. Essentially $h$ is the composition of three functions
$$
\begin{align}
f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m && f(x) \\
-:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m && -(x) = x - y \\
\|\cdot\|_{\mathbb{R}^m}:\mathbb{R}^m\to[0, +\infty) && \|\cdot\|_{\mathbb{R}^m}(x)
\end{align}
$$
Assuming $f$ is smooth, then both $f$ and $-$ are smooth functions, and so is $-\circ f$. The norm should also be smooth except at zero perhaps.

Comment: It is sufficient that $f$ is smooth and $y$ is not in the image of $f$. It's not necessary, for instance $y=0$ and $f(x)\equiv 0$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you for the comment. Why do we need the condition $y\notin \{f(x)\,:\, x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$?

Comment: @Euler_Salter The norm function is smooth everywhere except the origin, so we need $f(x) \ne y \; \forall x \in \Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Because of the 1D counterexample $|x|$

Comment: In fact you can even make $f$ discontinuous almost everywhere: Just let the image of $f$ be contained in the unit sphere centered at $y$, and then $h \equiv 1$.

Comment: @Zerox do you mind expanding that into an answer? I am not sure why $f$ can be discontinuous almost everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is why $f$ can be everywhere discontinuous.
Let $\varepsilon \in \Bbb{R}^m$ be a fixed unit vector. We construct $f: \Bbb{R}^n \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^m$ as follows:
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} y+\varepsilon & x \in \Bbb{Q}^n\\ y-\varepsilon & x \notin \Bbb{Q}^n \end{cases}$$
Then $f$ is everywhere dicontinuous (since $\Bbb{Q}^n$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}^n$) but $h(x)=\| \pm \varepsilon \| \equiv 1$ is smooth.

If you choose a smooth non-zero $\varepsilon$ rather than a constant $\varepsilon$, then you can make $h$ a non-constant smooth function while keeping the discontinuity of $f$.